# Multi site moderation

Tags: discussion, moderators

Is it possible for a user to be a moderator on more than one Stack Exchange site simultaneously?

Does Stack Exchange have any limitation(s) which restricts this kind of privilege?

Comment: Question 1: Yes. Question 2: No (afaik).

Comment: Thanks. Can you add that as an answer? For question 1, can you link to a documented source?

Comment: Worth to mention that several SE employees, e.g. [Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) have moderation diamond on ALL sites in the network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a list of users which are moderators on multiple sites, you can use [this page](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=users):

[image]

You cannot sort by number of sites they moderate, but browsing the list is quick enough.

Answer (score 7):

As someone who moderates a few sites on the network, yes, it's very possible (both in theory and practice). A number of people do it, though that's not a large fraction of the total set of Stack Exchange moderators. That said, I think the biggest limitations to the sites a person can mod are

- Time
- Expertise

You don't have to be an expert in each site you mod, but you should at least know a decent amount about it. Mods come from the community, first and foremost. They're not always the most active or knowledgeable folks there - although they do need [other qualities](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) - but they should be able, as a team, to understand at some level the content of most posts on the site. Not everyone knows everything about everything; for instance, my knowledge of [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) is . . . woeful.

The biggest limiting factor, though, is time. It takes a lot of effort and energy to moderate some sites, and this is even truer on large sites. The more flags a team has to handle, the larger the team, in general, but there's still always a lot to do. That's why it would be really hard to, say, moderate Stack Overflow and Programmers and Server Fault and Mathematics. On the other hand, four smaller, less busy sites are easier. Well, not easy. But easier.

You can't spread yourself too thin. That also takes effort. And hey, if you want to participate on a site you don't mod . . . you still need time for that, just to maybe keep your sanity in check.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible for a user to be a moderator on more than one SE site simultaneously (e.g. [Undo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo) is a moderator on both Stack Overflow and Software Recommendations).

To my knowledge there are no limitations to the number of moderator positions one can hold. However, being appointed requires sufficient activity on the SE sites, and being elected by the community.

Comment: The limitation is in getting appointed / elected on multiple sites, for which you have to be sufficiently active.

Comment: @Magisch Very true, will add that.

Comment: @Magisch that implies that although there isn't any technical limitation but a human limitation.

Comment: @rene you forgot [Rory Alsop](https://stackexchange.com/users/251740/rory-alsop?tab=accounts).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I solved it in a different way.

Comment: Pro-tem mods are appointed not elected :)

Answer (score 3):

> Does Stack Exchange have any limitation(s) which restricts this kind
>   of privilege?

Technically, no.

Multiple moderators are indeed moderators on several sites. [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310897/multi-site-moderation#comment1015761_310898) has provided a list of some in his comment.

But on a personal level, to become a moderator, one has to be active on the site and, in the case of graduated sites, popular enough to get elected. Barring a few outliers, that puts a limit on how many sites you can moderate at once, as every stack contributor also has only 24 hours in a day and most of them have jobs.